# When does this for loop escape?

Tags: javascript

To check my understanding, do we have that the following `for` loop never escapes only if `row.length < n` (otherwise, the loop can escape)?

```
function someFunction (matrix,n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    var row = matrix[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i += 1) {
      if (row[i] < 0) {
        alert("Something's wrong");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Eeeck.  Why are you using the same `for` loop index `i` in both `for` loops?  This will never do what you want.

Comment: confusing code. Both the inner and outer loop are using the $i$ variable name. Perhaps that can have something to do with it?

Comment: I know using the same index is bad.  I'm trying to understand what can go wrong and how when you do so.

Comment: It's pointless code.  Not worth diagnosing what it does because it should never be left the way it is.  Fix the code to do something useful and predictable for all expected inputs and something that follows decent coding practices.  You can see exactly what it does by just stepping through it in the debugger and watching the `i` variable get trounced around.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use the same incrementing variable in nested for loops!

```
function someFunction(matrix,n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    var row = matrix[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i += 1) {  //VERY BAD!!!
      if (row[i] < 0) {
        alert("Something's wrong");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the inner loop completes the first loop, i will equal row.length. This will also complete the outer loop, which increments i again by 1. Thus, when the outer loop goes to begin its second iteration, you will have i=row.length+1. Do this instead:

```
function someFunction(matrix,n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    var row = matrix[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j += 1) { //using j instead of i
      if (row[j] < 0) {
        alert("Something's wrong");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If `i = row.length + 1`, and `row.length + 1 < n`, then `i` will be reset to `0` again at the beginning of the inner loop.  Thus, the loop will never even finish.  Is this correct?

Comment: I believe you are correct. But also remember than row will be re-declared as matrix[row.length+1], so it may end eventually

Answer (score 2):

It's bad practice to use the same loop counter `i` for the inner and outer loops. That's just confusing and leads to unpredictable behaviour.

But since you have done so and you want to know what will happen:

When the inner loop finishes for the first time, `i` will have the value of `row.length` from the first `row` in your `matrix`. `i` will then be incremented by the outer loop. If this new value of `i` is `>=` your `n` variable then the outer loop will end immediately. Otherwise the outerloop will continue with the new value of `i` and execute this line:

```
var row = matrix[i];
```

At that point if `i` is greater than or equal to `matrix.length` the `row` variable will be `undefined`, so then when you get to the inner loop and try to test `row.length` you are testing `undefined.length` which will give you an error and stop execution.

But if `i` is less than or equal to `matrix.length` then the inner loop would "work" in the sense of running again with the new value of `row` and with `i` set back to `0` for its first iteration.

If the previous row's length happened to be same as its index minus 1 then the same row would be processed over and over forever.

So essentially every iteration of the outer loop is selecting a more or less random (and possibly undefined) row to continue with based on whatever the length of the previous row was.

Comment: When the inner for loop is hit for the second time (or I should say IF it is hit for the second time), is not `i` reset to `0`?

Comment: Yes, the inner loop sets `i` to `0` each time it starts. Assuming it gets there: as I mentioned, `row` may be `undefined` in which case you'll get an error and execution will just stop (it won't continue with whatever was after the outer loop).